# Map a list of strs to list of ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I want to convert strings that are ints in a list to integers.

If I have `a = ['1', 'ABC', '2', 'XYZ']`, then I'd like to make `[1, 'ABC', 2, 'XYZ']`. What will be a good Pythonic way of doing this?

I tried `a = list(map(int, a))`. However, this works only if each element is int already. E.g. `'1'`, `'2'`, `'100'`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to make a function that does the conversion for you.

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return x
```

Then

```
[convert(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def digit2int(x):
    if not isinstance(x,str):
        return x
    if  x.isdigit():
        return int(x)
    else:
        return x

[digit2int(x) for x in a]
```

use map function

```
list(map(digit2int,['1','2','333','hello']))
```

Comment: Ah, that's much better than mine.  Avoids the exception overhead.

Comment: @DanielWalker Simple is better than complex. haha

Comment: I don't think this is better than yours @DanielWalker. How much overhead is there in `try/except` vs `isinstance()` and `isdigit()`? [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) is generally considered a good practice in python. It also seem like the test for `isinstance(x,str)` is unnecessary.

Comment: I believe that it depends on how often you expect an exception to be raised.  If you think exceptions will be rare, then it can be better to "ask forgiveness rather than permission" (i.e., catch the exception).  However, although I don't know the specifics, I do now that catching an exception does have a non-negligible overhead.  You could test it with `%%timeit%%` in iPython/Jupyter.

Comment: I just ran `%%timeit` using the OP's example list and our two solutions.  @Bytesmith 's solution ran 3x as fast.

Comment: @DanielWalker I see a time difference of single digit nanoseconds here. I guess non-negligible is relative.

Comment: For a small amount of data, sure.